# Вывод данных в QLabel

Tags: python, ооп, gui, pyqt, qlabel

После открытия файла, мне необходимо прочитать его и вывести информацию из него на экран приложения.

В методе `initUI()` текст выводится нормально, но когда его пытаюсь модифицировать, ничего не происходит. 
Т.е. данные получены, я могу их вывести в `shell`, но на экран приложения никак не получается.

Подскажите, плиз, в чем я не прав?

```
import sys
import json
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import dijkstra, counts


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.lbl = QLabel("output:", self)
        self.lbl.move(20, 40)

        qbtn = QPushButton('Load file', self)
        qbtn.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)
        qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())
        qbtn.move(20, 20)

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Bacon number')
        self.show()

    def showDialog(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Load file', '')

        try:
            with open(fname[0], 'r') as input_data:
                graph = json.load(input_data)
                self.openFile(graph)

        except Exception as e:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Error', str(e))

    def openFile(self, graph):
        """ Подготовка результатов
            Из переменной graph получаю массив printResult """

        i = 0
        print (printResult)
        for result in printResult:
            self.lbl2 = QLabel(result, self)
            self.lbl2.move(20, 50 + i)
            self.lbl2.adjustSize()
            i += 10
            print (i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import json
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
#import dijkstra, counts

class Example(QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget) 

        qbtn = QPushButton('Load file')
        qbtn.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)
        self.lbl = QLabel("output:")

        layout = QGridLayout(central_widget)
        layout.addWidget(qbtn)
        layout.addWidget(self.lbl)
        self.setWindowTitle('Bacon number')

    def showDialog(self):
        fname, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Load file', '', "Json Files (*.json)")
        if fname:
            with open(fname, 'r') as input_data:
                graph = json.load(input_data)
            self.openFile(graph) 
        else:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Error', "Файл не выбран.")

    def openFile(self, printResult):   
        """Подготовка результатов"""
        """Из переменной graph получаю массив printResult"""
        for result in printResult:
            self.lbl.setText(self.lbl.text()+"\n"+result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]